# The type mismatch error while using Chisel3 BlackBox

Tags: riscv, chisel

I took `chisel-template` and tried using its infrastructure to run the basic example of the BlackBox, both the Chisel dummy part and the Verilog module part taken from [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/BlackBoxes#providing-implementations-for-blackboxes) and [here](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/BlackBoxes#blackboxes-with-verilog-in-a-resource-file).

I've copied over the existing folder/file structure and went into those files and replaced `GCD` and `gcd` by `TryBlackBox` and `tryblackbox`. I've also added the line: `import chisel3.util.HasBlackBoxResource`. Finally, I've positioned the `TryBlackBox.v` file into `src/main/resources/tryblackbox/` path.

When I try `test:runMain tryblackbox.TryBlackBoxMain` from within `sbt` I get 16 errors, all of them complaining about type mismatch, something like:

```
[error] /home/apaj/TryBlackBox/src/test/scala/tryblackbox/TryBlackBoxUnitTest.scala:79:60: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : () => tryblackbox.TryBlackBox
[error]  required: () => T
[error]     iotesters.Driver.execute(Array("--fint-write-vcd"), () => new TryBlackBox) {
```

I've uploaded my project to this repo:

```
https://github.com/apaj/TryBlackBox.git
```

I would appreciate any possible help in troubleshooting...

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track but there are several things biting you right now.

- A black box cannot be the *top* circuit, it must be referenced as an instance in a regular chisel module. The error you are getting is because TryBlackBox is a `BlackBox` and not a sub-class of a regular chisel Module.
- Eliminate the `object TryBlackBoxRepl` the repl is part of the firrtl interpreter and while it does have a black box capability of it's own, it requires a Scala implementation of the black box instead of verilog. I'd recommend taking this on later. There are examples of Scala black boxes in dsptools, firrtl-interpreter and treadle when you are ready.
- You must use verilator backend (or other verilog based backend), instead of the interpreter. You must specifically invoke using verilator manually by setting the args like

  ```
  object TryBlackBoxMain extends App {
    iotesters.Driver.execute(
      Array("--backend-name", "verilator"),
      () => new TryBlackBoxTop
    ) {
      c => new TryBlackBoxUnitTester(c)
    }
  }
  ```

> Note, in the code above I created a separate top module `TryBlackBoxTop` which is where you would instantiate `TryBlackBox`

- Since you are using `setResource("/tryblackbox/tryMe.v")` the file name of your resource should be `resource/tryblackbox/tryMe.v`. Probably a good idea to rename some of this a little bit also, using TryBlackBox too many places is probably going to get you in trouble.

Comment: Trying the first three points (sorry for a bit of a delay), but could you comment more on the fourth point. I agree different names could help find my way around, but I remember reading somewhere that the folder structure should resemble package structure in Chisel projects - that's why I propagated the name. Could you provide a recommendation on what should carry the same name and what not?

Comment: It seems I've managed to sort out the problem you pointed me to - please check the latest commit in the above mentioned repo. However, something new popped up - called itself: `[info] Running tryblackbox.TryBlackBox --help
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tryblackbox.TryBlackBox.main([Ljava.lang.String;)` and a lot more of Java stuff... it seems like a `scalaVersion` incompatibility, but all versions within this project are in agreement. Could you please take a look again?

Comment: No worry for delay, I've been out myself. There's not too much to more to day about my 4th point other than be careful about your names especially when working at the junctions of two languages, sometimes you want to make very sure the names match so that things work, sometimes you want to make sure that names are different so things don't collide.

Comment: I'm not sure about the java error. It's could be a number of things, but here's some suggestions. there is an implicit `args` variable when you extend App, you need to add `args` to the `Array(..."verilator"...)` or have the verilator params be part of the command line. Because you put your main in the src/test hierarchy you must use `test:runMain` when invoking it.  Also if you are running from sbt from bash or shell you must quote the entire string you want sbt to execute.  Try `sbt 'test:runMain tryblackbox.TryBlackBoxMain --help'`

Comment: Yep, that was it: `success`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the story efficiently, I've provided a detailed instruction on how to get the BlackBox running and avoid the Type Mismatch error right [here](https://github.com/Intensivate/learning-journey/wiki/Using-BlackBox).